# Android Imageview

Tags: android, imageview, resolve

I have kept some .png file in res->drawable-hdpi and now, I want to show it in imageview in android. But when I refer to that image from image view, android says:

> Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/my_pic.

I am using the following code :

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/my_pic" />
```

1. I am using every file name in small letter
2. The size of my_pic is 36kb

So how can I load the picture? Is this problem for size or something else. How to fix this problem. Any help ?

Comment: Have you refreshed your resources folder (click on it in the Eclipse package explorer and press F5) and cleaned the project? (Project -> Clean from the menus)

Comment: also is you picture in the drawable folder?

Comment: Yeahhhhhhhh it just worked like magic. Thanx  @Adam S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont save your changes, you get a

```
"Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/my_pic."
```

Control+S  ... to save Changes, its all or..

When the R.java have a problem, only needs:

```
(Project -> Clean from the menus)
```